# How to find symbol glutPostRedisplay() in Java?

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans

I'm trying to code a 2D game on Java with OpenGL, and I have the following function:

```
public void movement(int step) {
    GLUT glut = new GLUT();

    if (direct == 1) {
        move += 4;
        if (move == 36) {
            direct = 0;
        }
    } else {
        move -= 4;
        if (move == -8) {
            direct = 1;
        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(100 - tempo, movement, 1);
}
```

Netbeans gives me the `"Cannot find symbol"` error in both glutPostRedisplay and glutTimerFunc. How can I repair that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon which API version you are using, the methods glutPostRedisplay and glutTimerFunc are not defined. Checking the docs that came with the version you downloaded will help clarify this.

What version are you using?

Comment: Apparently version = 2.3.2. That's what I found in the library. Actually I was transcribing a C code to Java, and this methods were there